# How to interrupted the Thread in Android Fragment?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I am trying to interrupt the Thread , but it does't has interrupt item. The code is like the following:

```
    public class DeviceDetailFragment extends Fragment {

         public static CommunicationThread comThread;

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           comThread = new CommunicationThread();
           new Thread(comThread).start();
       }

         public static final class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {       
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Log.e("TEST", "Thread doing ");
                }
                Log.e("TEST", "Thread end ");
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        //stop the thread
   }
}
```

I want to interrupted the Thread in `onPause`. But it doesn't has `comThread.interrupted`.

**How to interrupted the Thread in Android Fragment ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just an unrelevant comment: calling a class that implement Runnable XThread is bad naming since it is not a thread but rather something that can be ran in a thread

Answer (score 1):

Maybe easier to set use a boolean variable which can be set be the caller and checked by the Thread.

```
    comThread = new CommunicationThread();
    new Thread(comThread).start();

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    comThread.stopThread = true;


    public static final class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {
          public boolean stopThread = false;

          while (!stopThread) {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public class DeviceDetailFragment extends Fragment {
         Thread mThread;
         public static CommunicationThread comThread;

       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           comThread = new CommunicationThread();
           mThread = new Thread(comThread);
           mThread.start();
       }

         public static final class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {       
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    Log.e("TEST", "Thread doing ");
                }
                Log.e("TEST", "Thread end ");
            }
        }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
         mThread.interrupt();
        //stop the thread
   }
} }
```

Comment: It will show error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread` at `mThread = new Thread(comThread).start();`

Comment: sorry do this `mThread = new Thread(comThread);` `mThread.start();`

Comment: Sorry for late...it has error at `mThread = new Thread(comThread);`. The log show `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Thread`.